# "is done" vs "was done" passive tense

Tags: phrase-usage

> Make sure that the computer program is done correctly via the link.
>
> Make sure that the computer program was done correctly via the link.
>
> You may sure that the computer program is correct via the link. (Can I say it like this?)

Which is correct?

It refers to [my it-article](https://habr.com/post/428644/).

Thanks.

Comment: make sure is to ensure; "may sure" is nothing. is done=present; was done, past.

Comment: Your third sentence needs to be amended to read either: *You may **ensure** that the computer programme is correct via the link* or *You **make** sure that the computer program is correct via the link.*

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your article, none of these are right.

You don't "do" a program, so the construction "is done correctly" in sentences 1 and 2 isn't right.

Also, to say a program is correct (like sentence 3) implies the program itself is a choice. E.g., "Which program would you use for creating a spreadsheet: Excel or Word?" In this case, the program might be correct. It's not strictly wrong, but it's not natural, because you're really asking whether the program is *error-free*.

**Better wording**

Try something like:

- Check your program [is working](https://ideone.com/1Wa1Dg).
- Use [this tool](https://ideone.com/1Wa1Dg) to check your program is working correctly.
- [Check your code is correct.](https://ideone.com/1Wa1Dg)
- [Check your code is working correctly.](https://ideone.com/1Wa1Dg)

(Note that, unlike a program, code can be correct.)